# awk update specific columns from file1 to file2. but include additional records from file1

Tags: awk

I realize there are a lot of awk NR=FNR questions and answers. I have had success but missing one piece. I need to update specific fields from file1.csv to file2.csv based on column 1 (guid) matching. This is working ok. My only issue here is that I need to also include records from file1 that do not exist in file2.  How can this be achieved?

file1.csv

```
guid,dyu,source,speech,french,hint1,morph1,morph2
z[fOXUyQT/,ɲyànafin,bk,adj,,,,
y1Ay6~2:)X,cɛ ka ɲi,bk,exp,joli,,,
993e663e-a3e4-4b7a-ba4a-1f4e982e4bf1,yɔ́rɔ,bk,n,endroit,,yɔrɔ,
f920d572-8185-41a1-8876-38940ea58604,bádenya,,,"fraternité, amitié, intime",,badenya,
"AM@~Gc,^|!",dencɛ,bk,,garçon / fils,,,
```

file2.csv

```
guid,dyu,source,speech,french,hint1,morph1,morph2
z[fOXUyQT/,ɲyànafin,yd,,nostalgie,,ɲyanafin,
y1Ay6~2:)X,cɛ ka ɲi,yq,,joli,,,
```

**desired output**

```
guid,dyu,source,speech,french,hint1,morph1,morph2
z[fOXUyQT/,ɲyànafin,bk,adj,nostalgie,,ɲyanafin,
y1Ay6~2:)X,cɛ ka ɲi,bk,exp,joli,,,
993e663e-a3e4-4b7a-ba4a-1f4e982e4bf1,yɔ́rɔ,bk,n,endroit,,yɔrɔ,
```

what I have so far:
(This updates the fields but does not add the missing record)

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","; FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}
            {
             if (NR==FNR) {
                 guid[$1]=$1;
                 a3[$1]=$3;
                 a4[$1]=$4;
                 next
             }
             {
               if ($1 in guid)
                 {
                 $3 = a3[$1];
                 $4 = a4[$1];
                 }
               print
             }
            }' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any duplicate `$1` values within either file as is the case with the example in your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    file1rec[$1] = $0
    next
}
$1 in file1rec {
    split(file1rec[$1],file1flds)
    $3 = file1flds[3]
    $4 = file1flds[4]
    delete file1rec[$1]
}
{ print }
END {
    for (key in file1rec) {
        print file1rec[key]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.csv file2.csv
guid,dyu,source,speech,french,hint1,morph1,morph2
z[fOXUyQT/,ɲyànafin,bk,adj,nostalgie,,ɲyanafin,
y1Ay6~2:)X,cɛ ka ɲi,bk,exp,joli,,,
993e663e-a3e4-4b7a-ba4a-1f4e982e4bf1,yɔ́rɔ,bk,n,endroit,,yɔrɔ,
```

The above was done before you added quoted fields containing commas to your example. Change from FS to FPAT as in the script in the question to accommodate that.

Comment: Thank you!   I can see what's happening here with saving $0 to an array and splitting it.   just a question:  Is the delete file1rec[$1] optional?   I will also have to wrap my mind around the for (key in file1rec) statement.   Isn't the key $1?   (just trying to understand whats happening...)

Comment: The delete isn't optional. Try commenting out that line to see what happens. If you don't delete the records from file1 that match the records from file2 as you go then  they'll all still be present when you get to the END section so that loop in the END section will print the entire contents of file1 instead of just the lines from file1 that didn't match lines from file2.

Comment: Yes, `key` is being assigned the value of each `$1` that was used as an index when populating `file1rec[]` and is still remaining after file2 is processed. Add a print statement to dump it inside the loop if you're not sure what it is.